# phpMyAdmin version 3.5.4 on Resin 4.0.38

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, resin

I plan to use resin web server on production, to replace the use of both my apache reverse server and tomcat, so operationally we just maintain 1 web server instead of 2.

I managed to install old version of phpMyAdmin (3.5.4) in resin, and I can login using MySQL using root user of my MySql.

My problem is: **I cannot see the list of Databases, on both left panel and center panel**.
There is a warning regarding PHP mysql lib:

```
"Your PHP MySQL library version 5.1.00 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.16. This may cause unpredictable behavior"
```

I checked on this behavior by googling, and most of it said that is because the user which I use as control user is not having enough privileges. But that's not possible in my case, since the user which I use is the root user of MySql.

I'm not sure this is resin issues, because logically resin quercus should encapsulate everything required by phpMyAdmin to run.

By the way, I'm using mysql-connector-java-5.1.0-bin.jar in /resin/lib. And running under windows 7, with JDK 7.

If anybody has experienced using resin to run phpMyAdmin, please help.

Thank you
Bromo

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to privileges. On your server, you have a mismatch between the MySQL client library used by PHP, and the MySQL server. So, for some type of queries, you'll get weird results and you should install a more up to date MySQL client library.

Comment: Yes I believe that too, I actually follows recommendation for choosing  java connector version and download 3 version (the latest and 2 archived) .. and try one by one but still I have the same problem .. :)

By the way, Marc ... have you succeed deploying phpMyAdmin on resin server? (I mean not Apache)